# USB flash memory not detected

Tags: drivers, usb

i have a problem in detecting usb flash memory. i used this command

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:c100 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:2113 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

what should i do ?

Comment: The first one looks like a USB drive. Are you using Ubuntu? What is the real problem?

Comment: yes i'm on Ubuntu .. i couldn't see flash usb to use it , i edited the post with what i see although i'm now connecting usb to laptop

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Is the flash drive formatted. is it seen in "Disks" utility?

Comment: 18.04.4 .. yes i tried to format usb then this problem happened

Comment: So it means that you did something wrong. Most likely it is not formatted.

Comment: how can i solve it ?

Comment: Format it properly. Install `gparted`, run it, select the USB drive and post a screenshot.

Comment: i edited the post, i found that usb not mounted

Comment: So try to mount it. But first format it. Right-click to get options.

Comment: i tried but got what i edited in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flash drive is mounted to `/mnt`, that's why you don't see it as a separate "disk".

Run

```
sudo umount /mnt
sudo mkdir /media/usb_drive
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb_drive
```

But you can run the first command only, unplug the device and plug it again to let it automount.